# Can't make superuser: error no such column

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi I try make superuser to login my admin panel but I recieved this error while making superuser:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: accounts_user.password1
```

and this is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_publisher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def change_user_type(self):
        if self.is_publisher:
           self.is_superuser = True
        self.save()
```

Comment: Don't store password by yourself. You have `password` field from `AbstractUser` class. It should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store two password in db. Just check those in FE validation.Since you inherit the AbstractUser automatically you are getting password field by default.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
      email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
      is_publisher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  
      def change_user_type(self):
          if self.is_publisher:
             self.is_superuser = True
          self.save()
```